# Generating random values using numpy

Tags: numpy, random, normal-distribution

I assign normal rv with mean 12 to ultimately generate order_date for my mock data. But when i am checking it out to see whether 12 is  most used value, it turns out to be not. Any recommendations why it is the case...

```
def random_date_generator(month):
  day_range = calendar.monthrange(2020, month)[1]
  day = random.randint(1, day_range)
  **first_hour = int(np.random.normal(12, 2))**
  # second_hour = int(np.random.normal(18, 2))
  hour = random.choices([first_hour])[0]
  minute = random.randint(1, 59)
  
  date = dt.datetime(2020, month, day, hour, minute).strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M")
  return date

columns = ['Order ID', 'Product', 'Quantity Ordered', 'Price Each', 'Order Date', 
'Purchase Address', "Month"]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
    
order_id = 123
for month_int in range(1, 13):
    if month_int == 12:
      order_amount = int(np.random.normal(100, 30))
    
    if month_int == 11:
      order_amount = int(np.random.normal(90, 30))
    
    if month_int < 11:
      order_amount = int(np.random.normal(60, 10))

    for i in range(order_amount):
      products_list = [product for product in products]
      weights = [products[key][1] for key in products_list]
      
      product = random.choices(products_list, weights=weights)[0]
      price = products[product]
      date = random_date_generator(month_int)
      address = generate_random_addresses()   
      month = calendar.month_name[month_int]
      
      df.loc[i] = [order_id, product, "NA" ,price, date, address, month_int]
      order_id += 1
    
    df.to_csv(f"{month}_data2.csv")
    print(f"{month}_data2.csv")
    break


january = pd.read_csv("January_data2.csv")
january["Hour"] = january["Order Date"].str[-5:-3]
january.groupby("Hour").count()
```

That is the output and as you see the most generated time is 12 but 10.

```
Unnamed: 0  Order ID    Product Quantity Ordered    Price Each  Order Date  Purchase Address    Month
Hour                                
07  2   2   2   0   2   2   2   2
08  2   2   2   0   2   2   2   2
09  9   9   9   0   9   9   9   9
10  15  15  15  0   15  15  15  15
11  11  11  11  0   11  11  11  11
12  10  10  10  0   10  10  10  10
13  9   9   9   0   9   9   9   9
14  7   7   7   0   7   7   7   7
15  3   3   3   0   3   3   3   3
```

Comment: For one thing, the line `hour = random.choices([first_hour])[0]` does absolutely nothing. Have you run this through a debugger to see what your data looks like?

Comment: For another, I am unable to reproduce the issue. I tried this: `plt.hist(np.floor(np.random.normal(12, 2, size=1000)).astype(int), np.arange(25) - 0.5)`. This plots the histogram of a normal distribution centered on 12. Half the time the peak is at 12, half the time at 11. This is expected, since you are truncating, not rounding.

Comment: Actually, random.choices returns list which i can not pass to datetime as hour..

Comment: That actually somehow occuers in the output aas 11 got more than 12 but problem is with the 10.

Comment: Btw, what do you mean by truncating. Could you explain further?

Comment: `int(x)` trucates the decimal portion of `x`. `round(x)` rounds it. If you take a normal distibution centered on 12 and round it, the peak should always be at 12. If you truncate it, it will be at 12 half the time, and at 11 the other half

Comment: You need to learn how to run things in a debugger to investigate what your own code is doing.

Comment: Thanks i got your point on truncating. i am gonna run it in debug mode to see actually what happens behind scene since i really did not get it.